# VBA to Download, Extract and Import to Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone tailor this script for me?  I asked for help in the original question (26486871) but my request was deleted.

This script does what I need:  downloads a zip file from a public website, extract the file...and imports the data into a worksheet.

However, I have 2 exceptions:

1. There is no csv file in the zip.  It only contains a text file (20MB).
2. I don't want a new worksheet.  I want to overwrite the existing data in a worksheet from a previous import.

I've tinkered with this script for 2 days but it gets stuck on the following:

"Run-time error '3001':  Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."

On that error, the script editor points to Stream.SaveToFile targetFile, 1  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite

If this makes a difference, the zipped text file has tab spaces separating the data to align the text-to-columns.

I'd like to thank Miguel Febres for developing this script.

I would appreciate any help.

---

```
'Main Procedure
Sub DownloadAndLoad()

    Dim url As String
    Dim targetFolder As String, targetFileZip As String, targetFileCSV As String, targetFileTXT As String

    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    url = "http://www.example.com/data.zip"
    targetFolder = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & RandomString(6) & "\"
    MkDir targetFolder
    targetFileZip = targetFolder & "data.zip"
    targetFileCSV = targetFolder & "data.csv"
    targetFileTXT = targetFolder & "data.txt"

    '1 download file
    DownloadFile url, targetFileZip

    '2 extract contents
    Call UnZip(targetFileZip, targetFolder)

    '3 rename file
    Name targetFileCSV As targetFileTXT

    '4 Load data
    Call LoadFile(targetFileTXT)

End Sub

Private Sub DownloadFile(myURL As String, target As String)

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile targetFile, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub    

Private Function RandomString(cb As Integer) As String

    Randomize
    Dim rgch As String
    rgch = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    rgch = rgch & UCase(rgch) & "0123456789"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To cb
        RandomString = RandomString & Mid$(rgch, Int(Rnd() * Len(rgch) + 1), 1)
    Next

End Function

Private Function UnZip(PathToUnzipFileTo As Variant, FileNameToUnzip As Variant)
    ' Unzips a file
    ' Note that the default OverWriteExisting is true unless otherwise specified as False.
    Dim objOApp As Object
    Dim varFileNameFolder As Variant
    varFileNameFolder = PathToUnzipFileTo
    Set objOApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ' the "24" argument below will supress any dialogs if the file already exist. The file will
    ' be replaced. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx
    objOApp.Namespace(FileNameToUnzip).CopyHere objOApp.Namespace(varFileNameFolder).items, 24

End Function    

Private Sub LoadFile(file As String)

     Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file, Format:=xlCSV, Delimiter:=";", ReadOnly:=True)

     wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
     'here you just want to create a new sheet and paste it to that sheet
     Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
     With newSheet
         .Name = wkbTemp.Name
         .PasteSpecial
     End With
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     wkbTemp.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: "It only contains a text file (20MB)." tells us nothing .. You can put few sample lines from the file or specify if it is tab delimited, fixed width, etc.

Comment: The text file is tab delimited.

Comment: then you can try something like `Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file, Format:=xlTextWindows, Delimiter:=vbTab, ReadOnly:=True)` or adjust it to match the format

Comment: That's great.  However, the script errors before the import.  It errs because it assumes there is a csv file inside the zip.  I should have asked a question like the original poster did.  I need a vba script to download a zip from a public website...extract the tab-delimited text file...and import the data into the current worksheet.  The import would overwrite any previous import.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bruce look at the following. It should solve your download problem.

```
'' This function downloads a file from a given webpage named 'url' and copies it to 'copylocation' named as 'filename'.
'' It is vital to check which format does the content has. For example: xlsx, csv, txt etc. This must be determined in 'downloadformat'.
'' If an already existing file should be overwriten, then overwritefile = TRUE must be set.
''
'' Example of use: GetWebpageContent("http://www.snb.ch/n/mmr/tcoreference/Current%20Rates/Interest_Rates/source/interest_rates.xlsx",
''              "F:\public\CurrentMarketRates",
''              "SARM", "xlsx", TRUE)
''
Function GetWebpageContent(url As String, copylocation As String, filename As String, downloadformat As String, overwritefile As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, fname As String, res As Boolean
    Dim owritef As Integer
        owritef = 1
    ''do not overwrite, unless overwritefile = TRUE
    If overwritefile Then
        owritef = 2
    End If
    ''create filename and location
    res = True
    fname = "\" & filename & "_" & Year(Now) & "." & downloadformat

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile copylocation & fname, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

    GetWebpageContent = res
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your script.  I've solved my download problem.  Right now I'm troubleshooting my unzip problem.

Comment: @Bruce Did you ever get this going? Would be useful to me.

Comment: I did get it going; however, I have to use two different functions.  I couldn't get the import to work with the Download and Unzip macro.  After I run Download & Unzip, I run the Refresh All command under the Data tab to import the data.